# Rtd pullup Connection?

Tags: sensor, rtd

I have 10v output and analog input, i dont have constant current source 1ma or dont want to use whetsonebridge circuit, my question is can i read rtd sensor output with pull up resistor Xk, if yes what must be value?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I think this is not possible, since the gradient of Pt100 is 0.038 ohm/celsius. Even if you put the pull up resitor you won't be able to measure the temperature with an ADC.

Comment: To give you a good answer, we need to know the analog input range, the resolution of the input and your required temperature resolution.

Comment: Analog input range +-10v, 16bit resolution and my required temperature resolution 2 celcious error at most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ratiometric voltage measurements are possible - the ADC reference voltage must be used for the pull-up (Ra) for the PT100 like this: -

[image]

Ra has to be chosen so that sufficient signal is developed across the PT100 to generate sufficient accuracy (given the ADCs bit resolution) without too much self-heating of the device.

It won't be a direct conversion to temperature because there is a potential divider effect i.e. if you used a current source, PT100 resistance converts directly to voltage. Not so with a ratiometric measurement of a PT100.

Comment: Keep the current below 1mA to minimize self heating

Comment: That means i can not directly pull up with 10v?

Comment: @Soso5 What is your ADC reference voltage? Is it internal inside some kind of MCU? It usually comes out on a pin BTW.

Comment: -+10v scaled to 0-5v with an integrated circuit component and connected to adc input. No reference voltage pin for adc.

Comment: Please provide a circuit to see if there is a way around this.

Comment: Andy if use two or three wire Pt100 model is it possible to use ccs and analog input from same pins.

Comment: I'm unsure about that.

Comment: Me too:) Guess i have 1ma ccs but 2 wire rtd so what?